# How to extract table information from a cell in dataframe using Scala in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to extract data which is tab separated from a cell in a dataframe row

I tried using the Splitted method but it wont work

```
val df = spark.sql("select _time, _raw, host from logs")

    val extractedData = df.filter(
      $"host" === "ausflscgap01.us.dell.com" ||
      $"host" ==="ausflscgap02.us.dell.com" ||
      $"host" === "ausplscgap01.us.dell.com" ||
      $"host" === "ausplscgap02.us.dell.com")
    .withColumn("splitted", split($"_raw", "\t"))
      .select($"splitted".getItem(5)
        .alias("pctIdle"))
      .show()
```

Actual Data in the row:

```
CPU    pctUser    pctNice  pctSystem  pctIowait    pctIdle
all       9.55       0.00      36.18       1.51      52.76
0        10.00       0.00      37.00       4.00      49.00
1         9.00       0.00      34.00       0.00      57.00
```

I need to extract the pctIdle column only for 'all' row
Expected Output

```
pctIdle
52.76
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your correctly, and you have "*Actual Data in the row*" in the text field *_raw* in the *logs* table, than you need something like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val extractPctIdle = udf{(raw: String) =>
raw
  .split("\n")
  .map(_.split("\t"))
  .find(_(0) == "all")
  .map(_(5))
  .getOrElse("unknown")
}

val extractedData = df.filter(
      $"host" === "ausflscgap01.us.dell.com" ||
        $"host" ==="ausflscgap02.us.dell.com" ||
        $"host" === "ausplscgap01.us.dell.com" ||
        $"host" === "ausplscgap02.us.dell.com")
      .withColumn("pctIdle", extractPctIdle($"_raw"))
      .show()
```

I.e. you can parse your _raw field by custom udf. 
It is simplest version, but it is better to do some error handling in case of malformed _raw field.

The case was modeled in this way:

```
case class R(host: String, _raw: String)

val df = Seq(
      R("ausflscgap02.us.dell.com", "CPU\tpctUser\tpctNice\tpctSystem\tpctIowait\tpctIdle\nall\t9.55\t0.00\t36.18\t1.51\t52.76\n0\t10.00\t0.00\t37.00\t4.00\t49.00\n1\t9.00\t0.00\t34.00\t0.00\t57.00"),
      R("ausplscgap01.us.dell.com", "CPU\tpctUser\tpctNice\tpctSystem\tpctIowait\tpctIdle\nall\t9.55\t0.00\t36.18\t1.51\t52.76\n0\t10.00\t0.00\t37.00\t4.00\t49.00\n1\t9.00\t0.00\t34.00\t0.00\t57.00")
    ).toDF()
```

**Edit**

If you need data from several columns inside _raw:

```
case class RawInfo(pctUser: String, pctIdle: String)

val extractRawInfo = udf{(raw: String) =>
      val all = raw
        .split("\n")
        .map(_.split("\t"))
        .find(_(0) == "all")

      def getValue(pos: Int) = all.map(_(pos)).getOrElse("unknown")

      RawInfo(
        pctUser = getValue(1),
        pctIdle = getValue(5))
    }

    df.filter($"host".isin("ausflscgap01.us.dell.com", "ausflscgap02.us.dell.com", "ausplscgap01.us.dell.com", "ausplscgap02.us.dell.com"))
      .withColumn("info", extractRawInfo($"_raw"))
      .select("host", "info.pctUser", "info.pctIdle")
      .show()
```

Remark: it is possibly to return just Array[string] from udf and retrieve specific columns later (like $"info"(0).as("pctUser")), but I prefer the typed solution shown above.

Comment: I get unknown as results but not the actual value

Comment: I appended code for modeling your case. Compare content of my _raw with your. May be some fixes are required.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me out

+------------------------+-------+
|host                    |pctIdle|
+------------------------+-------+
|ausflscgap02.us.dell.com|unknown|
|ausplscgap01.us.dell.com|unknown|
+------------------------+-------+

i followed your model and still it gives result as unknown

Comment: It is very strange. I receive exactly this with my code: +--------------------+-------+
|                host|pctIdle|
+--------------------+-------+
|ausflscgap02.us.d...|  52.76|
|ausplscgap01.us.d...|  52.76|
+--------------------+-------+

Comment: Thank you @skotlov.. the actual issue was the delimiter i used " +" and not "\t" and it worked. Thanks alot

Comment: One last question to wrap up if i need data from 0 and 1  as well how would i do it?

Comment: i have another question which i am going to ask and will tag you in that for your advice